# How to insert a list of lists into a database using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python list of list that I would like to insert into a MySQL database.
The list looks like this:

```
[[column_name_1,value_1],[column_name_2, value_2],.......]
```

I want to insert this into the database table which has column names as `column_name_1, column_name_2.....`

so that the database table looks like this:

```
column_name_1 | column_name_2 | column_name_3 | column_name_4

value_1       | value_2       | value_3       | value_4 

value_1       | value_2       | value_3       | value_4 

value_1       | value_2       | value_3       | value_4
```

How do I make this happen in python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the list have several values from the same column ? If that's the case how do you know which values go together in the same row ? Order ?

Comment: Column names will repeat each time there is a new value
eg: [[column_name_1,value_1],[column_name_2, value_2],[column_name_1,value_5],[column_name_1,value_6],[column_name_2,value_7......] so on

Comment: Is `column_name_1` always present in each insert ?

Comment: lets say that column name is 'Name', 'Address', 'gender'
list looks like :[[Name, John],[Address, XYZ],[gender, Male],[Name, Rose],[Address, ABC],[gender, female]......] and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort out the values depending on the column. Here is a way to do it that works with MySql's `executemany`, to make insertion faster.
If your list is named `val`:

```
dict = {val[0][0]:[]}
head_column = val[0][0] # A column that should be here in each row to be inserted

for value in val:
    if not value[0] in dict: # If we never saw that column
        dict[value[0]] = [""] * (len(dict[head_column]) - 1) # Then fill it with empty string
    if value[0] == head_column: # If we see the first column
        for column in dict:
            while len(dict[column]) != len(dict[head_column]): # We fill all column with emtpy string if they don't have a value
                dict[column].append("")
    dict[value[0]].append(value[1])

rows = []
for line in range(0, len(dict[head_column])):
    row = ()
    for column_name in dict:
        row += (dict[column_name][line],)
    rows.append(row)

sql_request = "INSERT INTO my_table ("
for column_name in dict:
    sql_request += column_name + ","
sql_request = sql_request[:-1] # Delete last ,

sql_request += ") VALUES ("
for column_name in dict:
    sql_request += "%s" + ","
sql_request = sql_request[:-1]
sql_request += ")"

cursor.executemany(sql_request, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are guaranteed to have a value for each column, you could do the following, which first groups these into rows based on the set of columns you have. If it's possible for column values to be missing you could switch it to key rows off of the appearance of the first column again (assuming that one is always guaranteed to be there). This data format is unusual and prone to bugs when it comes to determining row boundaries unless you have some guarantees about its format.

```
data = [
    ["Name", "John"],
    ["Address", "XYZ"],
    ["Gender", "Male"],
    ["Name", "Rose"],
    ["Address", "ABC"],
    ["Gender", "Female"]
]

columns = ["Name", "Address", "Gender"]
row = []
rows = []

for key, val in data:
    row.append(val)
    if len(row) == len(columns):
        rows.append(row)
        row = []

# The specifics of everything below will depend on your database and connection library. 
sql = (
    "INSERT INTO my_table (%s) VALUES (%s)" %
    (', '.join(columns), ", ".join(["?" for i in columns]))
)

conn = ...
cursor = ...
cursor.executemany(sql, rows)
```